# FlutterFire iOS Google Sign In not working, Platform Exception

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin, firebaseui, flutter-ios

I've been very successful in not getting iOS Google Sign In to work. No problem with Android. I got iOS and Android to work once together but I don't know how. I've failed five times after that, starting from scratch. I'm able to click the `Sign in with Google` button and the modal appears, but there's nothing in the modal. Not sure how that happens. Then when I cancel the modal the app crashes.

[I was following this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JgqcrQvGFzY)

**Here is the blank modal:**

[image]

**Here is the PlatformException:**

[image]

**Here is what I've done:**

**Ran flutterfire configure**

- Selected `android, ios, web`
- applied Firebase configuration for Android, `yes`
- Created a new Firebase project

**In Firebase Console**

- Downloaded `GoogleService-Info.plist`
- Didn't do `Steps 3 or 4` in `SDK Instructions` since the one time I got it to work I didn't do those steps, and every video I've watched skips them *(though I did try two times doing them, but to no avail)*

**In Xcode**

- chose `add files to "Runner"`, and added `GoogleService-Info.plist` that was downloaded from Firebase

**In ios/Runner/Info.plist**

Following the `google_sign_in` package, I added this code right before the last  tag, and change the ID as stated, which I got from the `GoogleService-Info.plist`

```
<!-- Put me in the [my_project]/ios/Runner/Info.plist file -->
<!-- Google Sign-in Section -->
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <!-- TODO Replace this value: -->
            <!-- Copied from GoogleService-Info.plist key REVERSED_CLIENT_ID -->
            <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.85...</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<!-- End of the Google Sign-in Section -->
```

**In main() added:**

then changed the `clientId`, which I got from the `GoogleService-Info.plist`

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  runApp(const MyApp());

  FlutterFireUIAuth.configureProviders([
    // iOS
    const GoogleProviderConfiguration(
      clientId:
          '85... .apps.googleusercontent.com',
    ),
  ]);

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:iosfire/auth_gate.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: const AuthGate());
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

This exception happens when the user cancels the modal. I'm not too concerned about this because it would probably not be an issue if the login worked correctly.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why do people downvote without giving a reason? It should be mandatory.

Comment: Please add platform exception error message.

Comment: @AayushBhattarai Nothing shows up in the Debug Console. The screenshot I added originally is the only information I get for troubleshooting this issue. Unless there's another way to get debug information that I'm not aware of.

Comment: on exception, go to run and debug tab in vs code, then you can see the actual platform exception message, and just update post with that screenshot

Comment: Added. This exception happens when the user cancels the modal. I'm not too concerned about this because it would probably not be an issue if the login worked correctly.

Comment: The message clearly mentioned that you canceled google Sign In.

Comment: Agreed. As I stated earlier, I'm not too concerned about this because it would probably not be an issue if the login worked correctly. I only concerned with signing in.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem is caused by CFBundleURLTypes which is duplicate from the deep linking.

I resolved by merge the custom scheme and domain.

please refer to my code below:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <!-- TODO Replace this value: -->
                <!-- Copied from GoogleService-Info.plist key REVERSED_CLIENT_ID -->
                <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.105469875803-qwerty</string>
                <string>customscheme</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>patp.com</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

Comment: For clarity the solution is to copy the REVERSED_CLIENT_ID text from the GoogleService-Info.plist and insert it where the com.googleusercontent.apps would be

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you could consider doing

1. Check the bundle id in info. Plist and Google services plist file. If they are different then there's a problem in configuration
2. Delete the application from your device and rebuild again
3. Make sure that your flutter channel is stable
4. Don't use the latest xcode. You can probably try 13.2 or 13.3
5. Delete Pods folder, Podfile.lock and. Symlinks folder and pod install and try again

Comment: Thanks for the info. Unfortunately, these steps didn't solve the issue. (1) There isn't a bundle id in `info.plist`. I did check the `REVERSED_CLIENT_ID` and that matches. (2) Uninstalled the app and reinstalled. (3) Flutter 3.0.5 * channel stable (4) Installed 13.3.1 (5) Deleted and tried again.